# Existence of Complementary Integrable Distribution

Tags: differential-geometry, foliations

Let $M^n$ be a smooth manifold. Let $D$ be a (regular) integrable distribution on $M$.

The question is whether there always (i.e. for any $M$ and $D$) exists an integrable distribution $D'$ on $M$ which is pointwise complementary to $D$, i.e.
at every point $p\in M$ we have $D_p \oplus D'_p = T_pM$.

**Note:** It is easy to prove that there exists a (not necessarily integrable) complementary distribution $D'$: one can take $D' := D^\bot$ with respect to a Riemannian metric on $M$. (There is a Riemannian metric on $M$ since by Whitney embedding theorem $M$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and hence can be equipped with the metric induced from the standard scalar product.) However, it is not clear why or whether $D'$ is integrable.

Comment: You are right that the orthogonal for a given Riemannian metric needs not be integrable.
For instance, if $H$ is the standard contact structure of $\Bbb R^3$, and $D = H^{\perp}$, then $D$ is a line distribution, hence integrable, but $D^{\perp} = H$ is not integrable.